Lack of control group in experiment?
I'm doing an experiment for Year 11 Biology to model how increasing the surface area of a potato affects the height of bubbles produced during a chemical reaction. It's supposed to show the interaction between the enzyme catalase and hydrogen peroxide. My current method involves cutting a potato into $\pu{24 cm2}$, $\pu{32 cm2}$, $\pu{40 cm2}$ and $\pu{48 cm2}$ pieces and measuring the height of bubbles produced after two minutes. How can I add a control group to this experiment, or am I just not thinking right and I already have one?
I'd appreciate any responses:)

What exactly do you mean by the height of bubbles and why is it a good quantitative parameter?

@Poutnik Sorry for the confusion! That parameter is mandated by the teachers, I'm pretty sure the amount of bubbles are supposed to reflect how much oxygen (product) is produced in the decomposition reaction of catalase and hydrogen peroxide.

I don't think there can be a control group. For instance, if you were boiling potatoes and then working with them to see how the temperature of the cooking water affects the presence of the enzyme catalase (interaction between the enzyme catalase and hydrogen peroxide), you could have kept an uncooked potato as a control. In the case of surface area, I don't really see a control(unless you have an invisible potato xD)

@Ronith Thank you so much!! That's what I was thinking as well:) I really appreciate the response!

Negative control: leave out the potato. Positive control: add $\ce{MnO2}$ instead. The purpose is to show that hydrogen peroxide is stable in the absence of the catalyst, and that the bubbles reflect the reaction of hydrogen peroxide and not something else (I don't know, the potato doing photosynthesis or some other red herring).

@Karsten Thank you so much for your response! :) I don't know much about chemistry, but would adding manganese oxide to hydrogen peroxide decompose hydrogen peroxide at a faster or slower rate compared to catalase? And would not having either negative or positive control in my method be a limitation of my experiment?

It depends on the details whether manganese oxide or the catalase enzyme is a better catalyst. For the control, you just establish that manganese oxide creates bubbles. If your potato fails to do the same, you know it's something about the potato (e.g. you cooked it), not some problem with the hydrogen peroxide solutions. Controls usually are qualitative. Limitations of experiments are often expressed with regard to the hypothesis. If your hypothesis is that all potatoes contain catalase, but then you test only Idaho Red, that's a limitation.

@Karsten Your answers are beyond helpful I really appreciate it!:)

BTW, horseradish peroxidase is very effective. Get the teacher to make this more interesting by comparing efficacy of potato and horseradish.
